# Usuing CURL to POST SAML Response in Spring-SAML

Tags: spring, curl, spring-saml

I am trying to use the CURL Command to POST the response receive from the IDP, i.e. the SAML Response to the SP on one of the alias which I have.
I am using Spring-SAML Framework.
Can someone help me with the exact command which needs to be used if I want to post the SAML Response to the SP using CURL Command ?

Answer (score 1):

SAML Response is fairly complicated and contains a range of values which expire over time, need to correspond to the originally send SAML Authentication Request and depend on configuration of the particular SAML federation. For these reasons there's no way to craft a generic CURL Command.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --data @path/to/file https://host
```

where file contains `SAMLResponse=` followed by the Base64 encoded and then URL-encoded SAML Response XML, e.g.

```
SAMLResponse=PHNhbWxwOlJlc3B...snip...R0cmlidXRlU3RhdGVtZW50PgogIDwvc2FtbDpBc3NlcnRpb24%2BCjwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U%2B
```

If you don't URL-encode the Base64 encoded string, any + characters will cause the XML to be truncated and parsing to fail. The errors I saw in the Keycloak logs were along the lines of `Element type "Response" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`